# You need at least 8.6 GB to install Ubuntu. This computer has 8.0 GB. (Lenovo Yoga 730-15 Dual-Boot Error)

Tags: lenovo

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 in dual-boot on my Lenovo Yoga 730-15 (8 GB RAM, 212 GB storage, i5 processor) with Windows installed. During the installation, I get this error message:

```
You Need At Least 8.6 GB disk space to install Ubuntu, This computer has only 8.0 GB.
```

I did the following steps:

- Downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 from the [official website](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
- Created a bootable 8 GB pen-drive using Rufus for my system's UEFI BIOS Mode.
- Created a 40 GB partition on my `C:\` drive.

Boot Steps:

- Pressed <kbd>F12</kbd>, which took me to the OS selection menu.
- Selected *Install Ubuntu*, which took me to the Ubuntu installation screen.
- Selected keyboard language.
- After selecting the language, the above problem occured.

What should I do?

Comment: Do not create a 40gb partition. After shrinking Windows by 40gb leave the space unallocated. Let the Ubuntu installer see unallocated space and create an `ext4` partition which Windows cannot create properly in the first place. Go back into Windows and delete the 40 GB partition you created there, assuming I read you correctly.